# (Python 3.7) Suddenly none of my modules can be imported…

Tags: python, import, module

`import numpy` returns `ModuleNotFoundError` and `pip3` returns Requirement already satisfied when I try installing it. These all worked last week.

[image: picture of terminal code]

It seems like `sys` and `os` still works… I don't recall doing anything funky that made this happen. I did some research and adding the package directory path to `sys.path` solves the issue for the lifespan of the terminal, but I need a permanent fix. I tried changing values in `.bashrc` but that didn't do anything and now I've discovered my `.bash_profile` and I'm messing around with this, but I don't really know what it is or the difference between this and my `.bashrc` file and the significance of the difference between `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.

Any clue whats going on? Tips? Fixes? If there's anything else I can put up here (pics of outputs, etc.) to help diagnose the problem I sure can do, just let me know.

Comment: Did I get hacked?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "none of my modules can be imported" mean? Can you provide a [mcve]? Or at the very least, a minimal example and the result you're getting? We're not mind readers. Please read [ask].

Comment: Are you using virtual environments?